# Having trouble implementing forever loop

Tags: c, for-loop, buffer, getchar, fflush

I seems to be having trouble with the forever loop, it seems to be working the first time i run the program but for some reason it seems to skip the option of asking the user if they would like to enter anymore CDs... Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
/* 
 * CourseProj.c
 * Create a program (database) that a record shop might use to track its 
    inventory of CDs
 * We need the following fields:
 * - Tittle, Artist, Number of tracks, Album/single, Price
 * This project must be commented
 */

 #include <stdio.h>

 main(){

 char    title [100][61];
 char    artist [100][61];
 int     num_tracks[100];      /* number of tracks on the CD */  
 float   price[100];         
 int     album[100];           /* boolean - is the CD an ALBUM? */
 char    type;                 /* used to read in album/single info */
 int     count = 0;            /* how many Cds are being tracked */
 int     i;                    /* loop counter */


 printf( "Welcome to the CD database.\n");
 printf( "You can store a maximum of 100 CDs.\n");

 /*
  * Loop until they no longer wish to enter any more CDs
  *
  */
 for (;;){      /* forever loops are convenient for this sort of thing */
   /*
    * Ask them if they want to enter another CD
    * Any answer other than y or Y wil be treated as a No
    */
   printf("\nHave you any more CDs to enter (y/n)? ");
   fflush(stdin);
   scanf("%c", &type);
   if (type != 'y' && type !='Y')
     break;


   printf("\n");   /* for neat output */

   // First, the title
   printf("Please enter the details of the CD %d... \n\n", count+1);
   printf("Title? ");
   fflush(stdin);
   scanf("%s", title[count]);


   // input the artist name
   printf("Artist? ");
   fflush(stdin);
   scanf("%s", artist[count]);

   // Now we need to input the number of tracks in the Album
   printf("Number of tracks? ");
   fflush(stdin);
   scanf("%d", &num_tracks[count]);

   // need to check if it's an Album or a single
   for (;;){
     printf("Album or single (a for album, s for single)? ");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf(" %c", &type);
     if  (type == 'a' || type == 's')
       break;
     printf("Error - only 'a' or 's' are allowed\n");
    }
    album[count] = type == 'a'; // if we get here it must be 'a' or 's'               


    //need to prompt the user for the price of the cd
    printf("Retail price (e.g. 4.65)?");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%f", &price[count]);
    count = count + 1;

    /*
     * Check if we have filled up the array
     */
    if (count == 100){
      printf("You have reached the limits of this program\n\n");
      break;
    }
   }
   /*
    * Output the CD details
    */
   for ( i = 0; i < count; i++){

     printf("\nThe details of CD %d are:\n", i+1);
     printf("==============================\n"); 
     printf("Title: %s\n", title[i]);
     printf("Artist: %s\n", artist[i]);
     printf("Number of track: %d\n", num_tracks[i]);
     //let check what the user input with the boolean


     if (album[i])
       printf("Album\n");

     else
       printf("Single\n");

     printf("Price: %.2f\n", price[i]); 
     printf("===========================\n");


     if ( i < count - 1){ // only do this if there are more CDs to see

     /*
      * A user-friendly way to progress to the next CD
      */
      printf("\nPress ENTER to see the next set of details: ");


      fflush(stdin);
      getchar();
     }
    }

    /*
     * A user-friendly way to exit the program
     */
     printf("\nPress ENTER to exit the program: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     getchar();
    }
```

Comment: Read the manuals for all the functions you use. Make sure you handle every case.

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin);` its behaviour is undefined. It may flush the input buffer, it may also not. The best way is to not use `scanf` and other input-consumers (such as `getchar`) together. Stick with one or the other. The problem is that `scanf` leaves trailing white-space in the input buffer, while consuming leading white-space. So `getchar` reads the left-over white-space and doesn't wait for 'new' input.

Comment: O ic, that might be the reason why it keeps breaking out of the loop after the first info was entered..

Comment: so i shouldn't be using fflush to clear the buffer nor use getchar?

Comment: Either use `scanf` for all input, or use `getchar` / `fgets` + `sscanf`. But [don't interlace `scanf` and `getchar` on the same stream](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html).

Comment: And never ever use `scanf("%s"...`, use `fgets` (as Kninnug said); the user doesn't know, that more than 60 input characters might crash the program, and even if he did, your program should handle that case gracefully. And (not really a mistake here, but kind of nonsense) you don't want floating points for prices. A floating point has a fixed mantissa and an exponent, what you want is "always two decimal digits after the dot": Use an integer type with values representing the pennies (or whatever currency you use) and write a function for outputting such a value with a dot.

Comment: Not related to your question, but if I may give you an advice: Don't write interactive software now, to do this in a clean way, you have to know some things about streams, buffering, memory allocation and error handling—use command-line parameters instead, and go back to interactive user interfaces some time in the future (when you know more about the aforementioned stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this chunk of code into your program to fetch the character from the user´s input.
It worked for me while I runned it in VisualStudio 2012.

```
printf("\n Have you any more CDs to enter (y/n)? ") ;
fflush(stdin);

type = getchar() ;

if( type == '\n')
{
   break ;
}

printf("you have typed : %c \n",type) ; /*print the character just to make sure that 
                                         it's the right one the user entered. */                                        

if (type != 'y' && type !='Y')
{
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct version. Whenever you want to stop waiting for the user to press a key you should "eat" the newlines! It means that if you acquire some data from the kwyboard with a scanf for instance, the user will press enter at the end to confirm the acquisition, that enter is a newline stored in the input buffer so I put some getchar() here and there to get rid of them. The fflush() does not work because it can only force stdout and stderr to be flushed. Solution is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char    title [100][61];
    char    artist [100][61];
    int     num_tracks[100];      /* number of tracks on the CD */  
    float   price[100];         
    int     album[100];           /* boolean - is the CD an ALBUM? */
    char    type;                 /* used to read in album/single info */
    int     count = 0;            /* how many Cds are being tracked */
    int     i;                    /* loop counter */


    printf( "Welcome to the CD database.\n");
    printf( "You can store a maximum of 100 CDs.\n");

    /*
    * Loop until they no longer wish to enter any more CDs
    *
    */
    for (;;){      /* forever loops are convenient for this sort of thing */
    /*
     * Ask them if they want to enter another CD
     * Any answer other than y or Y wil be treated as a No
     */
    printf("\nHave you any more CDs to enter (y/n)? ");
    scanf("%c", &type);
    getchar();
    if (type != 'y' && type !='Y')        
        break;

    printf("\n");   /* for neat output */

    // First, the title
    printf("Please enter the details of the CD %d... \n\n", count+1);
    printf("Title? ");

    scanf("%s", title[count]);


    // input the artist name
    printf("Artist? ");

    scanf("%s", artist[count]);

    // Now we need to input the number of tracks in the Album
    printf("Number of tracks? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_tracks[count]);

    // need to check if it's an Album or a single
    for (;;){
        printf("Album or single (a for album, s for single)? ");
        scanf(" %c", &type);
        if  (type == 'a' || type == 's')
            break;
        printf("Error - only 'a' or 's' are allowed\n");
    }
    album[count] = type == 'a'; // if we get here it must be 'a' or 's'               


    //need to prompt the user for the price of the cd
    printf("Retail price (e.g. 4.65)?");
    scanf("%f", &price[count]);
    getchar();
    count = count + 1;

    /*
     * Check if we have filled up the array
     */
    if (count == 100){
        printf("You have reached the limits of this program\n\n");
        break;
    }
    /*
     * Output the CD details
     */
    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++){

        printf("\nThe details of CD %d are:\n", i+1);
        printf("==============================\n"); 
        printf("Title: %s\n", title[i]);
        printf("Artist: %s\n", artist[i]);
        printf("Number of track: %d\n", num_tracks[i]);
        //let check what the user input with the boolean


        if (album[i])
            printf("Album\n");
        else
            printf("Single\n");

        printf("Price: %.2f\n", price[i]); 
        printf("===========================\n");

        if ( i < count - 1){ // only do this if there are more CDs to see
            /*
             * A user-friendly way to progress to the next CD
             */
            printf("\nPress ENTER to see the next set of details: ");
            while(getchar() != '\n');
        }
    }
}
/*
 * A user-friendly way to exit the program
 */
 printf("\nPress ENTER to exit the program: ");
 while(getchar() != '\n');
```

}